# Expressão regular, pegar números antes de um texto

Tags: regex

Queria uma expressão regular para pegar os minutos em uma string com esse formato:

```
1 min
10 min
```

Eu fiz essa expressão. [`\d(?= min)`](http://regexr.com/3bmpe)

O problema é que ela só pega o último número, o mais perto do min. Como eu pegaria o todos os números?

Comment: E se juntares um `+` depois de `\d`? -> http://regexr.com/3bmpn

Comment: Resolve, coloca como resposta que eu marco lá :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se  juntares um `+` depois de `\d` já funciona. Dessa maneira quer dizer *um número que ocorre uma ou mais vezes*. Sendo sem o `+` quer dizer somente *uma vez*.

```
\d+(?= min)
```

Exemplo: http://regexr.com/3bmpn